# Another Dynamically alias column question

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

I might be asking the same question as [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59062/how-can-i-dynamically-alias-columns), but perhaps if I ask it my way, a different solution may become obvious. I have this:

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE(
Table1ID Int Primary Key
,ColumnName varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO @Table1(Table1ID,ColumnName) VALUES(1000,'A')
INSERT INTO @Table1(Table1ID,ColumnName) VALUES(2000,'B')
DECLARE @Table2 AS TABLE(
Table2ID Int Identity Primary Key
,Table1ID Int
,FieldData varchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO @Table2(Table1ID,FieldData) VALUES(1000,'A DATA')
INSERT INTO @Table2(Table1ID,FieldData) VALUES(2000,'B DATA')
SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2
SELECT FieldData AS A 
from @Table2
WHERE Table1ID = 1000
SELECT FieldData AS B
from @Table2
WHERE Table1ID = 2000
```

And I want to do this:

```
SELECT FieldData AS [Table1.ColumnName]
from @Table2
WHERE Table1ID = 2000
```

Comment: Do you need to use table variables? Your life would be a lot simpler with #temp tables.

Comment: You really, really don't want to put a dot in the alias name.  Even though [Table1.ColumnName] is in square brackets and works, all sorts of other things in the SQL Server stack will break.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use #temp tables instead of table variables, this becomes dead easy.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
(
 Table1ID Int Primary Key,
 ColumnName varchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO #Table1(Table1ID,ColumnName) 
  VALUES(1000,'A'),(2000,'B');

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
  Table2ID Int Identity Primary Key,
  Table1ID Int,
  FieldData varchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO #Table2(Table1ID,FieldData) 
  VALUES(1000,'A DATA'),(2000,'B DATA');
```

Now, I can do this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @Table1ID INT = 2000;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT FieldData AS ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
  + N' FROM #Table2 WHERE Table1ID = @Table1ID;'
FROM #Table1 WHERE Table1ID = @Table1ID;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@Table1ID INT', @Table1ID;
```

Results:

```
B
------
B DATA
```

If you need to use table variables for some reason (as explained in an excellent answer by Martin Smith, [they're actually usually *less* desirable than #temp tables, or indifferent even in ways where most people make assumptions that table variables are better](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server)), then you can use a really fugly hack based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626292/how-to-use-table-variable-in-a-dynamic-sql-statement) (also by Martin Smith, coincidentally).

First, you need to create a table type in your database (and creating a copy of this in `model` may be a good idea as well, because in some scenarios it may need to also exist in `tempdb`).

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Table2 AS TABLE
(
  Table2ID Int Identity Primary Key,
  Table1ID Int,
  FieldData varchar(max)
);
```

Now, your code would be:

```
DECLARE @Table1 AS TABLE
(
  Table1ID Int Primary Key,
  ColumnName varchar(max)
);

DECLARE @Table2 AS dbo.Table2;

INSERT INTO @Table1(Table1ID,ColumnName)
 VALUES(1000,'A'),(2000,'B');
INSERT INTO @Table2(Table1ID,FieldData)
 VALUES(1000,'A DATA'),(2000,'B DATA');

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @Table1ID INT = 2000;

SELECT @sql = N'SELECT FieldData AS ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
  + N' FROM @Table2 WHERE Table1ID = @Table1ID;'
FROM @Table1 WHERE Table1ID = @Table1ID;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, 
  N'@Table2 dbo.Table2 READONLY, @Table1ID INT',
  @Table2 = @Table2, @Table1ID = @Table1ID;
```

Results, again:

```
B
------
B DATA
```

From a simplicity (and portability / forward compatibility) perspective, I would argue for the former solution where you just use #temp tables instead of table variables and a TVP.